# Use of tag.slug instead of tag.title in a custom route

Tags: routes, tags

I've followed [this guide](https://craftcms.com/support/tag-urls) for creating a routes to list entries with specific tags. It is working fine except that I have muli-word tags so using the tag token from `Settings -> Routes` gives me urls like

`mysite.com/tags/my%20tag%20name`

I'd like to us the tag.slug instead which should allow me to have urls end in `.../my-tag-name` instead, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Is there a way to refer to tag.slug in craft/config/routes.php?

If so what should the custom route look like:

`'tags/what goes here?' => 'tags/_tag.html',`

**Updated**

The template code is:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}


{% block content %}

{% set tag = craft.tags.title(tag).first() %}

{% if not tag %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

<h2>Entries tagged with “{{ tag.title }}”</h2>

{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).order('title') %}

{% if entries | length %}

        {% for entry in entries %}
            {{ include('./partials/entryListItem.html', {'entry': entry}) }}
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No entries could be found with that tag.</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

and the include points to:

```
<div class='entry-list-item'>
        <h2><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h2>
        <p>
          <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
            <span class="sm-txt"> continue reading</span>
          </a>
        </p>
        {% if entry.tags | length %}
          <p class='sm-txt'>
          {% for tag in entry.tags %}
            <a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | url_encode }}">{{ tag.title }}, </a>
          {% endfor %}
          </p>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
```

The route is set in the dashboard `tags/(tag token)` points to tags/_tag.html

If I change the route to `tags/(slug token)` I get template error: variable tag does not exist.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using in your template and also what your route looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to change your route. Instead modify your template where you are linking the tag.

Instead of using

```
<a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | url_encode }}">{{ tag.title }}, </a>
```

Use

```
<a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.slug }}">{{ tag.title }}, </a>
```

**UPDATED**

To clarify the above snippet goes in the template that generates the link to take the the user to your `_tag.html` template, not in the `_tag.html` template itself.

Your route should be as below:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Above snippet updated to match your example above.

**UPDATE 3**

As the `tag` variable made available to your template is now the tag’s slug, make sure to update the code to query for the tag model to use the `slug` param.

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.slug(tag).first() %}
```

Comment: I get a 404 error when I do that

Comment: The above snippet goes in the template that creates the link to your tag not in your _tag.html template

Comment: I've added more code to the question. Sorry for the lack of clarity. For the route, I am not typing (tag token) I am using the token option provided by the edit route dialogue box. If I type /tags/tag_token in the URI I get 404

Comment: `tag_token` is not meant to be typed, it is a representation of the token option you are using. I added an image instead to clarify.

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I have

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what else to suggest. I am using `{{ tag.slug }}` with success on multiple sites at present

Comment: Thank you. It does seem like it should work. Hopefully someone else can weigh in.

Comment: @AndrewStaroscik I just updated the answer to add the changes to the criteria model we talked about in Craft Slack.

Comment: Nice catch @carlcs